# How to get the reference of playing MPMoviePlayerViewController after clicking on the UIwebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, mpmoviewcontroller

I have loaded the you-tube URL on the UIWebView. After I click on UIWebView it opens the video in MPMoviePlayerViewController. Actually I need to get the reference of this   MPMoviePlayerViewController as I need to overlay text on this video.
Another problem I am facing is that I am not able to auto play the video. I tried this [Youtube video autoplay on iPhone's Safari or UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010708/youtube-video-autoplay-on-iphones-safari-or-uiwebview) but doen't work for me.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use an UIWebView instead of the MPMoviePlayerViewController? I mean, the URL requested is the video itself? Then, better use the movieplayer.

Anyways if I'm not wrong, the UIWebView fails and loads the movieplayer. So check

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
 // I think this error is the 204, check it yourself
```

And when this happens, try getting the topviewcontroller (which should be the movieplayerview).

Not tested by myself, this is the first thing that came to my mind :P

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But MPMoviePlayerViewController is not playing you-tube video as in youtube there is no direct URL to the video....When i am trying in my iPhone simulator it shows a black screen for a while then the videoDidFinsih notification get called.Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller. Can you please guide me how to get the topViewcontroller?