# Disable autoplay of youtube video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, html, uiwebview, youtube

I want to disable the autoplay of youtube video files when using a UIWebView and the iPhone webpage of Youtube ( http://m.youtube.com ).

I've tried `webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES` but that doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to remove start of the media player?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010708/youtube-video-autoplay-on-iphones-safari-or-uiwebview tried this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005298/ios-disable-youtube-autoplay-in-wkwebview/43987417#43987417