# Play embeded youtube video on button press

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to embed a youtube video in your application, but rather than showing the user a preview thumbnail that can be touched, show a standard UIButton that loads the video directly into the actual youtube player when touched. After the user clicks done control would return to my application (as it does with embedded webview) Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use youtube custom URL scheme. Read it from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007895-SW1)

E.g.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_IDENTIFIER"]];
```

This approach will take you out of your app and open native Youtube app. I don't think there is any thing available in youtube player [options](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) to hide thumbnail.  For autoplay without tapping UIWebView please read answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010708/youtube-video-autoplay-on-iphones-safari-or-uiwebview) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385791/youtube-video-autoplay-inside-uiwebview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141652/youtube-embeded-video-autoplay-feature-not-working-in-iphone)

Comment: This will take the user out of the application. I want to embed the video in my app so that when they are finished watching, they are returned to the app.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Updating answer

Comment: Apple really needs to add a function `+openYoutubeID:(NSString*)` that will open the video in the fullscreen player.