# Disable YouTube autoplay in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, youtube

When I load mobile version of "youtube" (m.youtube.com) in `UIWebView` and click on some video, this video start playing automatically. Can I disable this behavior? I already tried this:

```
self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES;
self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = NO;
```

But this is not helping.

I'm developing an app for downloading "youtube" videos and I really need to disable this auto playing feature for better user experience.

Comment: Take a look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010708/youtube-video-autoplay-on-iphones-safari-or-uiwebview 
this may help you.

Comment: I think this is not relevant for what I trying to do. I want to disable autoplay.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005298/ios-disable-youtube-autoplay-in-wkwebview/43987417#43987417